# How to make a random generator number which changes the number live randomly in time?

Tags: javascript

I need a random generator number to use on an HTML table cell. This random generator number should change automatically the number randomly in time. It is best if I can also choose something like a change number randomly between 3 and 5 minutes.  Additionally, I need to choose the range of numbers, for example, 0.02 to 0.90. The change needs to appear on the HTML table cell without refreshing the page.
Do any of you have any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: please post the the code - what have you tried so for ?

Comment: generating random number is very common , you can even find an example on w3schools. for your live part, you can use `setTimeout`

Comment: I have no Idea to make something like that. I only know the normal random number generator with Math.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<script>
function setRngTableCell(cell) {
    var e = document.getElementById(cell);
    e.innerHTML = Math.random();  //generate between 0 and ~0.999999
    startTimer();
}
function startTimer() { //sets a timer between roughly 1 and 2 minutes
    setTimeout(function() { setRngTableCell("mycell"); }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 60000) + 60000));
}
startTimer();
</script>
```

Then you need to give your table cell an id:

```
<td id="mycell">
```